# Using dd on video DVDs gets permission denied after about 700MB

Tags: backup, command-line, dvd, iso

I bought three movies on DVD on eBay. I am trying to make .iso backups onto my external hard drive. The first one I tried using Disk Utility, but it only produced a partial copy (without generating any errors) so I switched to using `dd`, which worked on the first movie. For both the second and third movie, `dd` only partially ran through before giving the following error:

`dd: /dev/disk2: Permission denied
1438432+0 records in
1438432+0 records out
736477184 bytes transferred in 212.743197 secs (3461813 bytes/sec)`

The number of records/bytes is similar, but not exactly the same, for both movies. I have no clue what else to try, since `dd` is as low-level a program I know to use. I have no idea why the error would be generated mid-copy like that. Googling for this kind of error leads to answers regarding improper filesystem permissions (I'm running `sudo dd`) and unmounting first (I'm also running `sudo umount`), and AFAIK neither would lead to `dd` working *for the first 700MB* and then getting that error.

Also, I have watched these movies all the way through without incident, so the filesystem appears to be good.

Comment: I've encountered this issue too. Rebooting has no effect, but if I take the same drive and disc to another macOS machine, it works. I tried in a different account and the issue is the same, so seems to be something related to the system.

Answer (score 4):

I've had some success. After trying a number of things unsuccessfully, including uninstalling packages that link into the filesystem, I found something that works reliably: load the disc using any software that reads the content and unlocks the encryption. Even the built-in DVD player works. Now after inserting a disc, I launch the DVD player and let the opening scene play. After that, dd seems to copy just fine.

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me, thanks! What I did exactly: 1. Reboot the system. 2. Start watching the DVD using the macOS DVD Player application. 3. After a minute or so, quit the application. 4. Using Disk Utility, UNMOUNT the DVD, but don't eject. 5. `ddrescue --no-scrape --sector-size=2048 --verbose /dev/diskX copy.iso copy.map`

Answer (score 2):

While writing this question, I remembered something I did different with the first disk and think I figured it out. For the second two disks I was using `sudo umount /Volumes/DISK_NAME` to unmount the DVD before running `dd`, which generated the permissions error, so I tried `sudo umount /dev/diskX`. This works, but only once per boot (it would fail again after one successful `dd`, until I rebooted). But can anyone explain *why* it worked? I thought the two invocations of `umount` were equivalent.

Comment: I ran into this problem, too. Indeed, it seems like the only solution is to reboot. I think the `umount` argument may be a red herring.

Comment: I wonder if the "once per boot" happens because there's some other low-level service that's starting up, and once it starts up, it's somehow interfering with the device and disallowing the copy.